# AJAX folder path issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So. My AJAX request works when I put the php file in the same folder as the html file with the AJAX. Like:

```
var URL = "question1.php?q1=" + radioValue;
```

Thing is though that I want to keep question1.php in another folder named "json". I've tried the following:

```
var URL = "/json/question1.php?q1=" + radioValue;
var URL = "json/question1.php?q1=" + radioValue;
```

But then the AJAX request skips the path before the folder json for some reason. Like:

```
http://localhost/json/question1.php?q1=Ok
```

..instead of

```
http://localhost/example/json/question1.php?q1=Ok
```

with "example" being where the ajax.html lies. I simply wanna be able to switch over the website to a server when I feel like it, without changing that path. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your **json** and **example** folder are on the level directory level and your ajax is executing from the path **/example**,  you need to do :

```
var URL = "/../json/question1.php?q1=" + radioValue;  // /../ would navigate to the parent of json and example.
```

which would internally look like :

```
http://localhost/example/../json/question1.php?q1=Ok
```

Comment: are both json and example on the same directory level ?

Comment: the html containing the ajax lies in /1214/ajax.html

Comment: question1.php lies in /1214/json/question1.php

Comment: try : var URL = "/1214/json/question1.php?q1=" + radioValue;

Comment: thanks but the thing is that I wanted to be able to move the files from server to localhost and vice versa without having to change. It's resolved though